# Can a marginal p.m.f. ever be exactly equal to the joint p.m.f.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ & $Y$ be two random variables (discrete or continuous). Are there any simple examples where the joint p.m.f. (or p.d.f.) equals one of the marginal p.m.f.s of $X$ or $Y$? I am just looking for examples, if any exist.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, no, since the joint distribution function is a function of **two** variables, while the (marginal) distribution function of $X$ is a function of **one** variable.

However, if $Y=a$ with probability $1$, and **we forget** about the distribution function of $(X,Y)$ when $y\ne a$, since $y\ne a$ "can't happen," then we do get what feels like equality. It really isn't.

Comment: I know in general the joint is two vars and marginal is one and equality doesn't hold in **general**. This is why I was asking for _examples_ (concrete or abstract) of when it does happen.

Comment: A function of two variables is never the same as a function of one variable. But for the example I give in the second paragraph, one could confuse the two, since the part outside $Y=a$ "doesn't matter." You can think of it as a joint distribution function given in "table" form, with only one column. But it is still technically wrong, since the $0$ values do matter, even if the table does not mention them.

Comment: I know that this is never true. What I am getting at is the following: In probability theory, if we are given a situation and asked to find the joint p.m.f. of two random variables, we know that **in general** this will be a function of both $x_1$ and $x_2$. But it _could_ happen that $f(x_1 , x_2)$ is independent (functionally) of $x_1$ (for instance). Such as if we are given two independent vars $X_1 , X_2$ and the distribution of $X_1$ is uniform. We might not know though from the situation that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

Comment: Let us look at the discrete case. We can have $f(x,y)$ independent of $y$ if there is some $b$ such that $\Pr(Y=b)=1$.  If $Y$ can take on at least two distinct values $b_1,b_2$ with non-zero probabilities, suppose $\Pr(X=a)=p\gt 0$. Then we cannot have $\Pr(X=a)=\Pr((X,Y)=(a,b_1))=\Pr((X,Y)=(a,b_2))$.

Comment: Ahh yes I am starting to see, this is beginning to clarify things for me. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the idea of a joint PMF/PDF "equaling" a marginal PMF/PDF isn't really the right way to think about things. In the case you mentioned, the joint PMF is a function of two variables wehereas the marginal PMFs are functions of one variable. Saying one is equal or unequal to the other doesn't really make sense.

With the joint PMF $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, we care about the outcome $X=x$ and $Y=y$ happening together at the same time.

The marginal PMF $f_X(x)$  is the probability of the random variable $X$ taking on the value $X=x$, regardless of the outcome of the random variable $Y$. When we marginalize over $Y$, we are saying "we don't care about the value of $Y$ anymore", so we sum over the values of all possible $y$'s to get rid of them.

$f_X(x)=\sum_y f_{X,Y}(x,y)$

Comment: You misinterpreted what I was asking. I understand what you say, and understood it before posting my question. The reason I was asking was because I was curious if there were somewhat contrived examples where $f_X(x) = \sum_y f_{X,Y} (x,y) = f_{X,Y} (x,y)$. I know this seems illogical, but this is why I am asking. I was thinking you might be able to construct a example where $f_{X,Y} (x,y) = h(x)$ was independent of $y$ and this happened to be equal to $f_X (x)$. For example, $X$ has a uniform dist. and $X$, $Y$ are independent, then $f(x,y) = f(x) f(y) = (1/a) f(y)$, in a discrete case.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.

If we say that $f_X(x) = \sum_y f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, then this means we only have one value of $y$ to sum over for all $x$. This means $Y$ has only one possible outcome.
So the special case you are looking for is where $Y$ is constant, or a degenerate random variable.

Answer (score 0):

A joint p.m.f. is a function of two variables, and is zero with at most  countably many exceptions.  It's impossible to have, say, 
$P(X=x,Y=y) = P(X=x)$ when $P(Y=y) = 0$ and $P(X=x) \ne 0$.

Similarly, for a joint pdf it's impossible to have $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)$ for **all** $y$.  It is possible to have $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)$ for $y$ in an interval  $[a,a+1]$ such that $P(a \le Y \le a+1) = 1$.  Simply let $Y$  have uniform distribution on this interval, and $X$ any continuous distribution, with $X$ and $Y$ independent.

Comment: I like your response, but can you tell me what would be wrong with constructing the following example: Let $X,Y$ be discrete random vars. and suppose $X$ has a uniform distribution and $X,Y$ are independent. Then, couldn't $f_{X,Y} (x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{a} f(y)$ ? What I am not understanding? If this is true, could it happen that $\frac{1}{a} f(y) = f_Y (y)$?

Comment: Why not just let $X\sim U[0,1]$ so that $a =1$? Then so long as $Y$ is a random variable defined almost surely in $[0,1]$ you should get $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_Y(y)$.